# Problem running WiFiWebClient example

Tags: wifi

I'm running the WiFiWebClient example which comes preloaded with Arduino IDE 1.6.7. I'm using Arduino Uno board with WiFi Shield Model R3.

```
/*
  Web client

 This sketch connects to a website (http://www.google.com)
 using a WiFi shield.

 This example is written for a network using WPA encryption. For
 WEP or WPA, change the Wifi.begin() call accordingly.

 This example is written for a network using WPA encryption. For
 WEP or WPA, change the Wifi.begin() call accordingly.

 Circuit:
 * WiFi shield attached

 created 13 July 2010
 by dlf (Metodo2 srl)
 modified 31 May 2012
 by Tom Igoe
 */
```

```c
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

char ssid[] = "Vanilla Sky"; //  your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "mypass";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;            // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
//IPAddress server(74,125,232,128);  // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
char server[] = "www.google.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue:
    while (true);
  }

  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  if (fv != "1.1.0") {
    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
  }

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  printWifiStatus();

  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80) == 0) {
    Serial.println("connected to server");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.google.com");
    client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
    client.println();
  }
}

void loop() {
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting from server.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while (true);
  }
}


void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

It gets my WiFi shield connected to `Vanilla Sky` but doesn't fetch the HTTP request (see image below). What is getting wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down :)

> Please upgrade the firmware

Visit here to upgrade the firmware of your board. Your original post doesn't show the fw version, but could have outdated library references and has been noted many times that outdated fw will not work.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/WiFiShieldFirmwareUpgrading

Also add this to your project to help us determine your firmware:

```
  Serial.print("Firmware version: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.firmwareVersion());
```

My guess is that it is less than 1.1.0. If the Arduino IDE is out of date, and the board is newer,  the NOT EQUAL TO(!=) may suggest that the firmware is newer than the library which could also be an issue.

Just b/c it connects to your router, doesn't mean that it can still communicate correctly.

One last side note, some versions of Arduino IDE have proven to be problematic with uploading a sketch to a wifi shield. A quick search with your Arduino version followed by the Wifi Shield not connecting could point you in the right direction. eg- Arduino x.xx wifi shield not connecting

Hope this helps!

Comment: My firmware version is 1.0.0 and it's not a concern unless you're using it for a sophisticated application. 1.0.0 should be able to do at least simple `GET` requests. I'm using Arduino Uno with the WiFi shield Model R3. My IDE version is 1.6.7